# ACTION_SENDTO can't find any email application

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using below code to send email using user's email application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "سفارش خرید");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "درخواست خرید محصول " + _name);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

but it can't find any email application on my device, though there are gmail and maildroid. I've used ACTION_SENDTO to filter the unneeded applications. but it doesn't work. any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi use the bellow code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "سفارش خرید");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "درخواست خرید محصول " + _name);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Although it shows skype, superbeam and terminal as well but I assume that's because they support that kinda message format. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Above answer works fine.But you can use this too, it will filter out only Email clients -

```
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "subject" + "&body=" + "body" +    "&to=" + "sendme@me.com");  
testIntent.setData(data);  
startActivity(testIntent);
```